# How to make an Array for Google Images Discord js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = ' .....';
const prefix = '-';

client.login(token);

client.on('message', (message) => {
 const image2 = message.content.slice(1);
 let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');

 switch (args[0]) {
  case 'random':
   image(message);
   break;
 }
});

function image(message) {
 const image2 = message.content.slice(7);

 var options = {
  url: 'http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=' + image2,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
   Accept: 'text/html',
   'User-Agent': 'Chrome',
  },
 };

 if (!image2)
  var options = {
   url: 'http://www.google.com/images?q=' + 'cursed+images',
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
    Accept: 'text/html',
    'User-Agent': 'Chrome',
   },
  };

 request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
  if (error) {
   return;
  }

  $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

  var links = $('.image a.link');

  var urls = new Array(links.length)
   .fill(0)
   .map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr('href'));

  console.log(urls);

  if (!urls.length) {
   return;
  }

  // Send result
  message.channel.send(urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
 });
}
```

Okay so i tried to get a random searched image to be shown in discord by my bot,
the function to get an Array for "results.dogpile.com" works
example : -image dog ( i get a dog image from choosing a random link from Array of result.dogpile.com

If i try : -image ( it doesn't show anything , due to the fact that the Array was made for results.dogpile not for google images user interface )

The question is ... how should i make the Array for google images to get a random image from search ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible, the issue with this is that you would need a database set up yourself with all the current google images you want available, since bots tend to struggle pretty often when connected to the web for browsing, I would recommend you look for a different dependency other than your dogpile thing. I will clarify though, I am no professional, so please, don't take my advice too much, it is only a suggestion from my point of view :)

Comment: i might give up on google image search , but how do I make the function to get random images from dogpile.com for MULTIPLE pages ? because it only randomized the one from FIRST page

Comment: @DeMoon So basically there are several pages on the dogpile.com? Do you scroll through the pages or are they a whole new webpage? If they are a whole new page, then it would require the bot have access to Google in a way that most likely wouldn't be easy to do. I believe it is possible though. You could try looking for a YouTube video tutorial, as they can be really helpful, even for experienced coders.